# How can I fix this stored procedure in mysql workbench I keep getting error code 1222

Tags: mysql, sql

Context: I'm basically trying to show the clients that have had two or more appointments and if they do then they are preferred clients but if they have less than two they are no preferred. However, I keep running into the problem stated above.

```
Use plastic_surgeon; 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_updated_preferred_status; 

ALTER TABLE clients 
ADD column client_status varchar (60); 

DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_updated_preferred_status () 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE client_status varchar (20); 

    Select c.ID, count(a.ID) as number_of_appts
    INTO client_status
    from clients as c
    join appointments as a
    on c.ID = a.Client_ID
    group by c.ID
    having count(a.ID) > 1 ;

    IF count(a.ID) > 1 THEN 
        SELECT 'preferred' as message;
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'not preferred' as message; 
    END IF; 

END//
DELIMITER ; 

Call sp_updated_preferred_status ();
```

Comment: Select ... into ... is used for variable assignment. You seem to need an update statement instead. But your update statement needs to update the table it selects from, so you will need to use subquery embedded into another subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT clients.ID,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(appointments.Client_ID) > 1
            THEN 'preferred'
            ELSE 'not preferred'
            END AS client_status 
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN appointments ON clients.ID = appointments.Client_ID
GROUP BY clients.ID
```

and respectively

```
UPDATE clients
  JOIN ( SELECT clients.ID,
                CASE WHEN COUNT(appointments.Client_ID) > 1
                     THEN 'preferred'
                     ELSE 'not preferred'
                     END AS client_status 
         FROM clients
         LEFT JOIN appointments ON clients.ID = appointments.Client_ID
         GROUP BY clients.ID ) AS data_for_update USING (ID)
SET clients.client_status = data_for_update.client_status
```